# Can anyone help getting a box to display using time as coordinates in Pinescript V5?

Tags: session, time, conditional-statements, drawing, box

Hi beginner coder apologise for being basic, im trying to learn to code with pinescript, i just want to draw a box around the NY open, with 9:30-10:30 as left and right sides, and the high and low price within that hour as the top and bottom.

Its for making backtesting easier so eventually want it drawn between the user inputted time period on every NY open, but for now I cant get one to display at all.

I'm not getting any errors, is there a problem with how i'm creating the condition to only draw the box within the two allowed time periods?

Or am I not even close? :)

`indicator("justabox", overlay=true)`

`startdate = input.time(timestamp("15 december 2022 04:00"), title = "Start Date")`

`enddate = input.time(timestamp("16 december 2022 04:00"), title = "end date")`

`nysess = not na (time("","0930-1030"))`

`daytime = time("1D")`

`onehour = 1000 * 60 * 60`

`oneminute = 1000 * 60`

`leftside = daytime + (onehour*9)+(oneminute*30)`

`rightside = daytime +(onehour*10) +(oneminute*30)`

`float top        = na`

`float bottom     = na`

`bool  indate     = na`

`if (timenow >= startdate and timenow<= enddate)`

```
`indate := true`
```

`else`

```
`indate := false`
```

`if (indate and nysess)`

```
`top := ta.highest(high,12)`

`bottom := ta.lowest(low,12)`

`boxy = box.new(leftside, top, rightside, bottom)`
```

I was expecting a box to be drawn between 9:30am and 10:30 am with its top and bottom set at the high and low price within that hour.

i tried simplifying the code down to just the user inputted time period as a condition and setting the box at last_bar_index[120]  and last_bar_index as its left and right without a session condition and i tried just drawing two lines at high and low price, im following tutorials and dont seem to be doing much different, but i cant find one specific to what im doing.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the current bar is within the NY open session

```
nysess = time("0930-1030")
```

If the current bar is within the NY open session, draw a box

```
if nysess
  top = high
  bottom = low
  leftside = time("0930")
  rightside = time("1030")
  boxy = box.new(leftside, top, rightside, bottom)
```

Comment: i'll try that, didn't realise i could just state a time, thanks